# OrderBy numbers and ThenBy boolean not working for List

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of Objects where I am trying to sort then by two iterations.

The first is sort the objects in Ascending order by an integer field in the object i.e 1-1000 and then sort by a boolean of true and false by a boolean field in the object.

What I have is...

```
    public void updateAdapter()
    {
        List<Object> foobar = db.Get(ObjectID);

        foobar = foobar.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Tag)).ThenByDescending(s => s.Duplicate).ToList();

        adapter = new ListAdapter(this, foobar);
        RunOnUiThread(() => adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged());
        ListView.Adapter = adapter;
    }
```

My list sorts perfectly by the integer field n ascending order but it doesn't sort by true values after that. I want all true values to go to the top of the list of objects after they have been sorted by ascending integer fields.

Sample Input:

```
Lists of Objects Inputted:
FooBar(11, false),
FooBar(1, false),
FooBar(54, true),
FooBar(34, true)
FooBar(77, false),
FooBar(33, false)

List of Objects Outputted:
FooBar(1, false),
FooBar(11, false),
FooBar(33, false),
FooBar(34, true),
FooBar(54, true),
FooBar(77, false),
```

Any help would be a huge help. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output data please? It sounds like you actually want to _first_ sort by `Duplicate` and _then_ by `Tag`.

Comment: Sure thing. Will add what I am getting and what I want :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your understanding of what orderby-thenby does is exactly backwards.

You believe, incorrectly, that orderby sorts the list first by integers, and then does a stable re-sort of the list by the Boolean property.  That would put all the trues together, sorted by integer, and all the falses together, sorted by integer.

That's not what it does.

The orderby sorts the list by integers, and then the thenby takes all the places where two records sorted to the same integer, and sorts that sub-list by the Boolean property.

This should match your intuition. If I handed you a bunch of cards with numbers and letters and said sort these first by number and then by letter, and I handed you 3A, 2B, 2A, 3B, that the result would be 2A, 2B, 3A, 3B, and not 2A, 3A, 2B, 3B, right?

So you want to reverse your clauses. First orderby the Boolean; that will put all the trues and falses together. Then do a thenby on the integer property, and all the trues will be sorted by integer, and all the falses will be sorted by integer.

That said, orderby in LINQ to Objects is required to be implemented as a stable sort, so if you really want to do it the hard way, you could do an orderby on the integer property and then a *second* orderby on the Boolean property, and you'd get the right result. But that's wasteful, since it sorts the entire list twice, rather than sorting the entire list once, and then sorting each sublist.  Sorting two half lists is usually cheaper than sorting one entire list.

Comment: That's really informative! I did, in fact, think it was the OrderBy and ThenBy to order the way I wanted. I also appreciate the better way of working on the ordering using LINQ. This did in fact help and solved my issue :). Thanks Eric.